# Using genealogy tree with hyperref and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, genealogy

Is it possible to create a genealogy tree with hyperlinks from the nodenumber to a biblatex file that is printed at the end as a reference list with relevant data about the person referenced in the node or a hyperlink to a `minipage` with details related to the node displayed on mouseover?

I was able to generate a tree with node numbers following the manual but not sure how to create hyperlinks in each node, any pointers in the correct direction would help.

MWE for the tree with generated node numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm,landscape,a0paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{blue}{Male}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{red}{Female}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{black}{Neuter}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\genealogytree[template=symbol nodes,level size=8mm,level distance=6.5mm,
box={title={\gtrnodenumber},height=5mm,attach boxed title to bottom center,
fonttitle=\fontsize{3mm}{3mm}\sffamily,
boxed title style={size=tight,height=3mm,valign=center,left=0.2mm,right=0.2mm}},
tcbset={mytext/.style={notitle,interior style={top color=gtr_Yellow_Frame!50!gtr_Yellow_Back,
bottom color=gtr_Yellow_Frame!50!gtr_Yellow_Back,middle color=gtr_Yellow_Back}}},
add parent=a to fam_a,add parent=b to fam_b,add parent=c to fam_c]
{
child{
gm pf cf
child{gm pf cf cm}
child{gm pf cm c- cm}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\cite` command works when placed in the box as in below MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,landscape,a0paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{1,
    author={John Doe},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }
@book{2,
    author={Jane Doe},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }  
@book{3,
    author={Jane Doe3},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    } 
@book{4,
    author={Jane Doe4},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }
@book{5,
    author={Jane Doe5},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    } 
@book{6,
    author={Jane Doe6},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    } 
@book{7,
    author={Jane Doe7},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }
@book{8,
    author={Jane Doe8},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }
@book{9,
    author={Jane Doe9},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }
@book{10,
    author={Jane Doe10},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }
@book{11,
    author={Jane Doe11},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }
@book{12,
    author={Jane Doe12},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{blue}{Male}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{red}{Female}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{black}{Neuter}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\genealogytree[template=symbol nodes,level size=8mm,level distance=6.5mm,
content interpreter content={\gtrifnodeid{\gtrnodeid}{n_{\gtrnodenumber}}},
% note cite command
box={title={\cite{\gtrnodenumber}},
height=5mm,attach boxed title to bottom center,
fonttitle=\fontsize{3mm}{3mm}\sffamily,
boxed title style={size=tight,height=3mm,valign=center,left=0.2mm,right=0.2mm}},
tcbset={mytext/.style={notitle,interior style={top color=gtr_Yellow_Frame!50!gtr_Yellow_Back,
bottom color=gtr_Yellow_Frame!50!gtr_Yellow_Back,middle color=gtr_Yellow_Back}}},
add parent=a to fam_a,add parent=b to fam_b,add parent=c to fam_c]
{
child{
gm pf cf
child{gm pf cf cm}
child{gm pf cm c- cm}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\blindtext[4]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

But if I placed the `\cite` command in the line

```
content interpreter content={\gtrifnodeid{\gtrnodeid}{n_{\gtrnodenumber}}},
```

thus

```
content interpreter content={\gtrifnodeid{\gtrnodeid}{n\cite{{\gtrnodenumber}}}},
```

it fails to generate the reference list.

Is there some other syntax to be used to get the citation link within the box?

Comment: I tried the following and the cite command works when placed in the box. as follows

Comment: You should remove one pair of braces around `\gtrnodenumber`: `content interpreter content={\gtrifnodeid{\gtrnodeid}{n\cite{\gtrnodenumber}}}` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You solution works fine for me, you just should use only one pair of braces around `\gtrnodenumber`. So, instead of

```
content interpreter content={\gtrifnodeid{\gtrnodeid}{n\cite{{\gtrnodenumber}}}}
```

you should write

```
content interpreter content={\gtrifnodeid{\gtrnodeid}{n\cite{\gtrnodenumber}}}
```

Full MWE (I used `@misc` instead of `@book`, although it might probably a good idea to even create a custom datamodel):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{1,
    author={John Doe},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}
@misc{2,
    author={Jane Doe},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}  
@misc{3,
    author={Jane Doe3},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
} 
@misc{4,
    author={Jane Doe4},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}
@misc{5,
    author={Jane Doe5},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
} 
@misc{6,
    author={Jane Doe6},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
} 
@misc{7,
    author={Jane Doe7},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}
@misc{8,
    author={Jane Doe8},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}
@misc{9,
    author={Jane Doe9},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}
@misc{10,
    author={Jane Doe10},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}
@misc{11,
    author={Jane Doe11},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}
@misc{12,
    author={Jane Doe12},
    title={\gtrsymBorn 1990},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{blue}{Male}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{red}{Female}
\gtrSymbolsSetCreateSelected{black}{Neuter}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\genealogytree[
    template=symbol nodes,
    level size=8mm,
    level distance=6.5mm,
    content interpreter content={
        \gtrifnodeid{\gtrnodeid}{n\cite{\gtrnodenumber}}
    }, % note cite command
    box={
        title={\gtrnodenumber},
        height=5mm,
        attach boxed title to bottom center,
        fonttitle=\fontsize{3mm}{3mm}\sffamily,
        boxed title style={
            size=tight,
            height=3mm,
            valign=center,
            left=0.2mm,
            right=0.2mm
        }
    },
    tcbset={
        mytext/.style={
            notitle,
            interior style={
                top color=gtr_Yellow_Frame!50!gtr_Yellow_Back,
                bottom color=gtr_Yellow_Frame!50!gtr_Yellow_Back,
                middle color=gtr_Yellow_Back}
            }
        },
        add parent=a to fam_a,
        add parent=b to fam_b,
        add parent=c to fam_c
    ]{
    child{gm pf cf
        child{gm pf cf cm}
        child{gm pf cm c- cm}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output tree:

[image]

Output reference list:

[image]